# AC wall unit producing clicking sound from a blue box (capacitor? I have included a video). Why and how I can fix this?

Tags: capacitor

I have an AC wall unit that is producing an intermittent (~1 time per 10 min) clicking sound since I bought it (2 years ago.)

Today I got tired of the sound, opened up the unit, and discovered that the clicking sound is coming from a small blue box that I think is a capacitor.

For example, on the blue box, I can read "BM 3uF". A quick google search brought me [here](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1mtJnayjrK1RjSsplq6xHmVXap/10pcs-lot-BM-CBB61-1uF-1-2uF-1-5uF-2uF-2-5uF-3uF-450VAC-Air-conditioning.jpg_q50.jpg&imgrefurl=https://www.aliexpress.com/i/32966131243.html&tbnid=3hVaQGwN7EIFGM&vet=1&docid=woAX4mqcbxHR7M&w=800&h=600&hl=en&source=sh/x/im).

UPDATE (June 9): Just noticed that behind the blue box, there is a relay ([SANYOU RELAYS SLI-S-112DM](https://lcsc.com/product-detail/Others_SANYOU-RELAYS-SLI-S-112DM_C276427.html).) Maybe my perception of the "click noise" coming from the blue box was wrong and in fact the click noise is coming that relay.

[image]

For info, I am able to "reproduce" (most of the time) the clicking sound by doing these steps:

1. change the thermostat temperature from 25 Celsius to 18 Celsius
2. wait 2-3 seconds
3. hear the clicking sound sound

Here is a video of me recording that [clicking sound.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eWFQgrqvmko)

Questions:

1. Why is this clicking sound occurring?
2. Can I reduce this noice? (Maybe by changing the component or wrapping it with a noise reducer material.)

Comment: Sounds like a relay working normally.

Answer (score 0):

It’s a bimetallic thermostat run cap for the air conditioner.  By design.  Use rubber mounts if it bothers you.

Comment: Thank you Tony for your answer. This said, I am not sure to completely understanding it. Looking on the web, I can see that this blue blox is a capacitor: https://tinyurl.com/8scst92c (mine is the 3uF model). Knowing that, with my limited knowledge in electronic, I don't see the relation between a "bimetallic thermostat" and a capacitor. Is there something I am missing? Thank you

Comment: Update: Just noticed that behind the blue box, there is a relay (SANYOU RELAYS SLI-S-112DM). Maybe my perception of the "click noise" coming from the blue box was wrong and in fact the click noise is coming the that relay.